# How do I bind this 1 variable using mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Ok, so I have been at this for hours now, and no matter what i do, it just doesn't work.  I've read pages of documentation and even tried verbatim by examples, and still doesn't work:

```
$db = mysqli_connect($db_server, $db_user, $db_passwd, $db_name);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$db_query = "SELECT ca.id_article, ca.title, ca.body, ca.id_tag, ca.visible, ct.title AS tag_title
            FROM cdfi_articles AS ca
            INNER JOIN cdfi_tags AS ct ON(ct.id_tag = ca.id_tag)
            WHERE ca.id_article = ?
            LIMIT 1";
;
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $db_query)) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $_REQUEST['article']);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $return);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

    var_dump($return);

}

mysqli_close($db);
```

The following error occurs and I don't know how to fix it at all:

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_result() [function.mysqli-stmt-bind-result]: Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in ... filepath on line {line number}
```

`bind variables` don't match?  I am only using 1 variable, and only 1 question mark within the query, what gives??

`var_dump($return)` returns `NULL` value

How can I fix this?  I just want to get that 1 row returned within the `$return` variable so that I can do something with it, arggg!

Comment: Why are you using `$_REQUEST`? Use `$_POST` or `$_GET` specifically

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll make that change!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are selecting 6 columns but you are only binding `$return` in `mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $return);`

Try

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $artid, $title, $body, $tagid, $vis, $tagtitle );
```

Comment: Ok, so I was thinking of this also, but how to fix this??  I just want all columns returned into the `$return` variable, so that the column names are within the $return array.  Is that possible?

Comment: Thanks, that gets rid of the error...  Thanks, I suppose it's not possible to have it return it into 1 variable that is an array huh?  That sucks!  Guess I have to use all of those variables now, and store it in the array manually!!

Comment: Arrays don't work very well with SQL/SQL doesn't work well with arrays, in my experience.

Comment: @SolomonClosson: I don't know if it's possible. You might try defining `$result=array()` before calling `mysqli_stmt_bind_result` and see what happens.

Comment: according to the documentation this should do what you want: `$r = $stmt->get_result(); $result = $r->fetch_assoc()` (or what type of array you like)

Comment: I need an associative array, but how can I do this procedurally?  Not crazy about object-oriented style, no offense to that style tho, just not my style.